# Function to print values of several index of array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

So I have an array, for example `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,6,1])`. I wanted to find where the minimum values of this array was so I did:

```
print np.where(a == a.min())
```

and obviously it printed 0, 5, 7. Now I have another array that has the same length as array a. Lets call that array b. I want to find the value of that array at index 0, 5, 7. I could just type b[0], b[5] and b[7]. But that is incredibly inefficient. Can someone please help me in how to write a function that will do that for me. I was thinking something like:

```
def location(h):
 h = np.where(a==a.min())
 print b[h]
```

but i don't think this right and i am not getting the right answer. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That **does** work.

Comment: So when you say "but i don't think this right and i am not getting the right answer." you need to be more specific.

Comment: I was using the wrong version of Python so I was getting weird errors. But it still helps that I got more efficient suggestions to accomplish the same task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.where(a == a.min())[0]` returns *(array([0, 5, 7], dtype=int64),)*, iterate through the array.

```
def location(a):
    vals = np.where(a == a.min())[0]
    for item in vals:
        print(b[item])
```

Using `map` and lambda expression. (Python3)

```
print(list(map(lambda x: b[x], np.where(a == a.min())[0])))
```

Python2.x

```
print list(map(lambda x: b[x], np.where(a == a.min())[0]))
```

Sorry I have python3 running, just change the print function to statement. Thanks.

Comment: The `print()` syntax should work in Python2 as well. Just Python3 doesn't work with `print ""`

Comment: Converting a numpy array into a list and using `map` is an inefficient way to do this - keeping everything in numpy and using built in methods will be far more effective

Answer (score 0):

`a == a.min()` returns a boolean array showing where values in `a` are equal to the minimum value in `a`.

You can use this array to index into any other array of the same length - `b[a == a.min()]` will return an array of length 3 containing the values you want.